# Vulnerabilities of having one path of app accessible only via HTTPS but others via HTTP?

Tags: web-application, tls, attacks, cookies, same-origin-policy

Imagine `example.com` that is accessible via HTTP and HTTPS. Most of content at site isn't secure and it won't be bad if it will be read by attacker. One of paths - `example.com/secure_zone` is accessible only via HTTPS and contains information that shouldn't be accessed by attacker. `example.com/secure_zone` has its cookie with path set to `/secure_zone` with `httponly` and `secure` attributes.

Are there any security issues here? Is there a difference if cookie doesn't have httponly attribute?

Note: Attacker in MITM position can fully access contents of http://example.com/some_path but can't access https://example.com/secure_zone thanks to Javascript's SOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), and the HttpOnly and Secure [attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie), induce the same general model, which is that your HTTP site and your HTTPS site will be seen by the browser as two distinct animals, thus   cleanly separated. In practice, this is not entirely true; for instance, while the cookies from the HTTPS site will have the "secure" flag and will not be sent to the HTTP site, the converse is not true. An active attacker, by manipulating data as it flows between the client and the HTTP site, could inject a cookie which will be sent to the HTTPS site.

Usually, it is safer and simpler to go full-HTTPS. It is safer mostly in the following sense: it allows you to educate your users into expecting an end-to-end HTTPS site, with the padlock icon. This makes the *users* less vulnerable. But these users also connect to your site and use its features, so a vulnerable user is also a problem for you.